Geometry Two-Column Proof Question

Given: $\angle a$ is congruent to $\angle D$
Prove: $\triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle DEF$
The solution to the problem is very easy because of AA similarity. However, I'm wondering how drawn-out I should be with my two column proof.
I have
$\angle a$ is congruent to $\angle d$ : given
$\angle 2$ is congruent to $\angle 4$ : given
$m\angle 1 + m\angle 2 = 180$ : they are linear pair
$m\angle 3+ m\angle 4=180$ : same
$\textbf{$m\angle 1 = m\angle 3$ : substitution and subtraction}$
$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DEF$: AA similarity (1, 5)
The step is highlighted in bold: does it need to be stretched out or is it enough for most teachers?

This is enough. Two-column proofs are intended to be a stepping stone to more rigorous proof writing, where you can begin to skip some steps so long as the reader can follow.

To ensure a student is not only seeing things clearly but able to communicate clearly and precisely (the point of this exacting kind of proof), I would prefer to see something like $1+2=3+4, 1+4=3+4 \rightarrow 1=3$, where the thinking and rationale are crystal clear. It is true that we start to skip bigger and bigger steps as we go further in an area, but that is earned by experience and it sounds like you are at the beginning. Whether your current form is enough will depend on your teacher.

thank you so much!

@RobinSparrow you don't know how confused I felt after seeing your comment because I didn't bother the diagram at first in the post

@Gwen: Works mod 2 too I suppose :)
